Backyard lawn questions
so I live in Alabama and when we bought our home this past march we were pretty much banking on our backyard grass growing in. I believe the sod (Bermuda grass) that they laid down for us was not cared properly so I am left with dead grass and poor soil quality. I have quack and crabgrass all throughout my back yard and it’s literally an eyesore. I was wonder what would you do in this situation that I am in. 
If there is anything I can get to help my grass grow in and kill these weeds that are all over the lawn I would greatly appreciate any expert advice.


You could not expect the sod people to change your soil. But can you use nature's sign of the bad-grass area to say that's your new garden plot?
